# Passing values directly to setter method using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, getter-setter

this my getter and setter:

```
private int[] test;

public int[] getTest() {
    return Arrays.copyOf(test, test.length);
}

public void setTest(int[] test) {
    this.test= Arrays.copyOf(test, test.length);
}
```

And here is my code for manually passing values to the setter method

```
Sample sample = new Sample();   
sample.setTest(new int[]{0,1,2,3});
```

what I want is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //code here for passing the value to the setter
}
```

This is working on my side, is there a way to pass this values using a for loop? Also I want to know how to pass in an array as a whole?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Can you show an example of what you are trying to write?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > 3; i++)` I think you mean `i < 3`

Comment: You can push the value into an array in loop and pass through setter or just create another method to push a single value to your private property.

Comment: Still, nice question ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat thank you :) hope this question will help others too :)

Comment: @Càphêđen thank you for the comment I will take note of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass a `for-loop` as values for the new `test` array values.

What you can do is write a sepearate function that generates an int array for you out of a `for-loop`:

```
public int[] getNumbers(int start, int end, int increment) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (int i = start; i < end; i += increment) {
        values.add(i);
    }
    return values.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

Which could then be used as such (as per the `for-loop` in your question):

```
sample.setTest(getNumbers(0, 3, 1));
```

Or for more simple arrays (so just a range of ints from startNumber to endNumber with an increment of 1) you could do the following:

```
sample.setTest(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray());
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and giving me other options as well! :)

Comment: Really nice ;-), like it ... Also "nice" of you to leave out a subtle detail allowing me to put up another answer ;-) x2

Answer (score 1):

The answer by nbokmans is spot on; but I suggest to step back here and have a look at your requirements.

What I mean: you should decide if you want

- an interface that allows passing in an array as a whole
- an interface that allows passing in single values

In other words: if it is a **common** thing for you to *add* single values to that field ... then you should **design** your interface accordingly. Like this:

```
public class Whatever {
  private final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();

  public void append(int value) {
    data.add(value);
  }

  public void getData() {
    return new ArrayList<>(data);
  }
```

for example.

Comment: thank you for this answer and for explaining it to me, what I want is an interface that allows passing in an array as a whole. I will update my question.